# combine two codes to function as one command

Tags: python

i have a problem regarding two codes that i wished to combine to function as one. my project is a class attendance using fingerprint, and i'm doing it on raspberry pi. it requires me to download the image of the fingerprint scanned after a successful matching. right now i can match the finger and download the image scanned on my sensor, and i can do both separately, but not at once. what i want to do is to have the sensor match the fingerprint and proceed to scan the fingerprint again to download the image in a single command. can anyone help me with this? the codes are as below:

matching the fingerprint:

```
import hashlib
from pyfingerprint.pyfingerprint import PyFingerprint


## Search for a finger
##

## Tries to initialize the sensor
try:
    f = PyFingerprint('/dev/ttyUSB0', 57600, 0xFFFFFFFF, 0x00000000)

    if ( f.verifyPassword() == False ):
        raise ValueError('The given fingerprint sensor password is wrong!')

except Exception as e:
    print('The fingerprint sensor could not be initialized!')
    print('Exception message: ' + str(e))
    exit(1)

## Gets some sensor information
print('Currently used templates: ' + str(f.getTemplateCount()) +'/'+ str(f.getStorageCapacity()))

## Tries to search the finger and calculate hash
try:
    print('Waiting for finger...')

    ## Wait that finger is read
    while ( f.readImage() == False ):
        pass

    ## Converts read image to characteristics and stores it in charbuffer 1
    f.convertImage(0x01)

    ## Searchs template
    result = f.searchTemplate()

    positionNumber = result[0]
    accuracyScore = result[1]

    if ( positionNumber == -1 ):
        print('No match found!')
        exit(0)
    else:
        print('Found template at position #' + str(positionNumber))
        print('The accuracy score is: ' + str(accuracyScore))

    ## OPTIONAL stuff
    ##

    ## Loads the found template to charbuffer 1
    f.loadTemplate(positionNumber, 0x01)

    ## Downloads the characteristics of template loaded in charbuffer 1
    characterics = str(f.downloadCharacteristics(0x01)).encode('utf-8')

    ## Hashes characteristics of template
    print('SHA-2 hash of template: ' + hashlib.sha256(characterics).hexdigest())

except Exception as e:
    print('Operation failed!')
    print('Exception message: ' + str(e))
    exit(1)
```

download the image:

```
import tempfile
from pyfingerprint.pyfingerprint import PyFingerprint


## Reads image and download it
##

## Tries to initialize the sensor
try:
    f = PyFingerprint('/dev/ttyUSB0', 57600, 0xFFFFFFFF, 0x00000000)

    if ( f.verifyPassword() == False ):
        raise ValueError('The given fingerprint sensor password is wrong!')

except Exception as e:
    print('The fingerprint sensor could not be initialized!')
    print('Exception message: ' + str(e))
    exit(1)

## Gets some sensor information
print('Currently used templates: ' + str(f.getTemplateCount()) +'/'+ str(f.getStorageCapacity()))

## Tries to read image and download it
try:
    print('Waiting for finger...')

    ## Wait that finger is read
    while ( f.readImage() == False ):
        pass

    print('Downloading image (this take a while)...')

    imageDestination =  tempfile.gettempdir() + '/fingerprint.bmp'
    f.downloadImage(imageDestination)

    print('The image was saved to "' + imageDestination + '".')

except Exception as e:
    print('Operation failed!')
    print('Exception message: ' + str(e))
    exit(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

match the fingerprint & download the image:

```
import hashlib
import tempfile
from pyfingerprint.pyfingerprint import PyFingerprint

## Search for a finger
##

## Tries to initialize the sensor
try:
    f = PyFingerprint('/dev/ttyUSB0', 57600, 0xFFFFFFFF, 0x00000000)

    if ( f.verifyPassword() == False ):
        raise ValueError('The given fingerprint sensor password is wrong!')

except Exception as e:
    print('The fingerprint sensor could not be initialized!')
    print('Exception message: ' + str(e))
    exit(1)

## Gets some sensor information
print('Currently used templates: ' + str(f.getTemplateCount()) +'/'+ str(f.getStorageCapacity()))

## Tries to search the finger and calculate hash
try:
    print('Waiting for finger...')

    ## Wait that finger is read
    while ( f.readImage() == False ):
        pass

    ## Converts read image to characteristics and stores it in charbuffer 1
    f.convertImage(0x01)

    ## Searchs template
    result = f.searchTemplate()

    positionNumber = result[0]
    accuracyScore = result[1]

    if ( positionNumber == -1 ):
        print('No match found!')
        exit(0)
    else:
        print('Found template at position #' + str(positionNumber))
        print('The accuracy score is: ' + str(accuracyScore))

    ## OPTIONAL stuff
    ##

    ## Loads the found template to charbuffer 1
    f.loadTemplate(positionNumber, 0x01)

    ## Downloads the characteristics of template loaded in charbuffer 1
    characterics = str(f.downloadCharacteristics(0x01)).encode('utf-8')

    ## Hashes characteristics of template
    print('SHA-2 hash of template: ' + hashlib.sha256(characterics).hexdigest())

except Exception as e:
    print('Operation failed!')
    print('Exception message: ' + str(e))
    exit(1)    

## Reads image and download it
##

## Tries to initialize the sensor
try:
    f = PyFingerprint('/dev/ttyUSB0', 57600, 0xFFFFFFFF, 0x00000000)

    if ( f.verifyPassword() == False ):
        raise ValueError('The given fingerprint sensor password is wrong!')

except Exception as e:
    print('The fingerprint sensor could not be initialized!')
    print('Exception message: ' + str(e))
    exit(1)

## Gets some sensor information
print('Currently used templates: ' + str(f.getTemplateCount()) +'/'+ str(f.getStorageCapacity()))

## Tries to read image and download it
try:
    print('Waiting for finger...')

    ## Wait that finger is read
    while ( f.readImage() == False ):
        pass

    print('Downloading image (this take a while)...')

    imageDestination =  tempfile.gettempdir() + '/fingerprint.bmp'
    f.downloadImage(imageDestination)

    print('The image was saved to "' + imageDestination + '".')

except Exception as e:
    print('Operation failed!')
    print('Exception message: ' + str(e))
    exit(1)
```

Comment: This may solve your problem but let me know if you would like some kind of explanation or if you want to use functions or separate files